# Finding the values of positive peaks in smooth wave form

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

This is some code I wrote to search for the peaks of a very clean (no noise) signal where `fun` is an array containing evenly sampled data of a sine wave.

```
J=[fun(1)];
K=[1];
count=1;
for i=2:1.0:(length(fun)-2)
    if fun(i-1)<fun(i) && fun(i)>fun(i+1)
        J=[J,fun(i+1)]; 
        K=[K,count+1];
    end 
    count=count+1;
end
```

Included below is the data that I am trying to process.

The code found the peaks at the 664th and 991st entry, but none of the ones in between. I wrote the same algorithm in c++ and got the same result, so it is an algorithm problem, not language specific.

Please help me find the error or give me another solution.

```
fun = -1*pi/180*[-90.15
-90.00
-89.70
-89.10
-88.50
-87.75
-86.70
-85.65
-84.30
-82.95
-81.45
-79.80
-78.15
-76.35
-74.55
-72.30
-70.20
-67.80
-65.40
-62.70
-60.00
-57.15
-54.30
-51.15
-48.00
-44.85
-41.40
-37.95
-34.50
-30.90
-27.30
-23.55
-19.80
-16.05
-12.15
-8.25
-4.95
-1.50
1.95
4.80
7.80
10.65
13.95
17.40
20.70
23.85
27.15
30.30
33.45
36.45
39.45
42.45
45.30
48.00
50.70
53.40
55.95
58.35
60.75
63.15
65.25
67.35
69.45
71.40
73.20
74.85
76.50
78.15
79.50
80.85
82.05
83.25
84.15
85.05
85.95
86.70
87.45
88.05
88.50
88.95
89.10
89.25
89.40
89.25
89.10
88.95
88.50
88.05
87.45
86.70
86.10
85.20
84.30
83.25
82.20
81.00
79.65
78.15
76.65
75.00
73.35
71.55
69.60
67.50
65.40
63.30
60.90
58.65
56.10
53.55
51.00
48.30
45.45
42.60
39.75
36.75
33.75
30.60
27.45
24.30
21.00
17.70
14.40
11.10
7.65
4.80
1.95
-0.90
-4.35
-7.65
-11.10
-14.85
-18.75
-22.35
-26.10
-29.70
-33.30
-36.75
-40.20
-43.50
-46.80
-49.95
-52.95
-55.95
-58.65
-61.35
-63.90
-66.45
-68.85
-70.95
-73.05
-75.00
-76.80
-78.45
-80.10
-81.60
-82.95
-84.15
-85.20
-86.10
-87.00
-87.60
-88.05
-88.50
-88.80
-88.80
-88.80
-88.80
-88.50
-88.05
-87.60
-87.00
-86.25
-85.50
-84.45
-83.25
-82.05
-80.55
-79.05
-77.40
-75.60
-73.65
-71.55
-69.45
-67.20
-64.65
-62.25
-59.55
-56.70
-53.85
-50.85
-47.70
-44.55
-41.25
-37.95
-34.50
-30.90
-27.30
-23.70
-19.95
-16.20
-12.45
-8.55
-5.25
-1.95
1.50
4.35
7.20
10.05
13.35
16.65
19.95
23.10
26.40
29.55
32.55
35.55
38.55
41.40
44.25
47.10
49.80
52.35
54.90
57.30
59.70
61.95
64.05
66.30
68.25
70.20
72.00
73.65
75.30
76.80
78.30
79.65
80.85
81.90
82.95
83.85
84.75
85.50
86.10
86.55
87.00
87.45
87.60
87.75
87.75
87.75
87.60
87.30
87.00
86.55
85.95
85.35
84.60
83.70
82.80
81.75
80.55
79.35
78.00
76.50
75.00
73.35
71.70
69.75
67.95
65.85
63.75
61.50
59.25
56.85
54.45
51.90
49.35
46.65
43.80
40.95
38.10
35.10
32.10
28.95
25.95
22.65
19.50
16.20
13.05
9.75
6.90
4.05
1.05
-1.80
-5.10
-8.40
-11.70
-15.45
-19.20
-22.95
-26.55
-30.15
-33.60
-37.05
-40.35
-43.65
-46.80
-49.95
-52.80
-55.65
-58.50
-61.05
-63.60
-66.00
-68.25
-70.50
-72.45
-74.40
-76.20
-77.85
-79.35
-80.70
-81.90
-83.10
-84.15
-85.05
-85.80
-86.40
-86.85
-87.15
-87.45
-87.45
-87.45
-87.30
-87.00
-86.55
-85.95
-85.35
-84.45
-83.55
-82.50
-81.30
-79.95
-78.45
-76.95
-75.15
-73.35
-71.40
-69.30
-67.05
-64.65
-62.25
-59.70
-57.00
-54.15
-51.30
-48.30
-45.15
-41.85
-38.55
-35.25
-31.80
-28.20
-24.60
-21.00
-17.25
-13.65
-9.90
-6.60
-3.30
0.15
2.85
5.70
8.55
11.40
14.70
17.85
21.15
24.30
27.45
30.45
33.45
36.45
39.30
42.15
44.85
47.70
50.25
52.80
55.20
57.60
59.85
62.10
64.20
66.30
68.10
70.05
71.70
73.35
75.00
76.35
77.70
79.05
80.25
81.30
82.20
83.10
83.85
84.45
85.05
85.50
85.95
86.10
86.40
86.40
86.40
86.25
86.10
85.65
85.35
84.75
84.15
83.40
82.65
81.75
80.70
79.50
78.30
77.10
75.60
74.10
72.45
70.80
69.00
67.05
65.10
63.15
60.90
58.65
56.40
54.00
51.45
48.90
46.20
43.50
40.65
37.80
34.95
31.95
28.95
25.80
22.65
19.50
16.35
13.05
9.90
7.05
4.20
1.35
-1.50
-4.65
-7.95
-11.25
-15.00
-18.75
-22.35
-25.95
-29.40
-32.85
-36.30
-39.60
-42.75
-45.90
-49.05
-51.90
-54.75
-57.45
-60.15
-62.55
-64.95
-67.20
-69.30
-71.40
-73.20
-75.00
-76.65
-78.15
-79.50
-80.70
-81.90
-82.80
-83.70
-84.45
-85.05
-85.50
-85.80
-85.95
-86.10
-86.10
-85.80
-85.50
-85.05
-84.60
-83.85
-82.95
-82.05
-81.00
-79.65
-78.30
-76.95
-75.30
-73.65
-71.70
-69.75
-67.65
-65.40
-63.15
-60.60
-58.05
-55.35
-52.50
-49.65
-46.65
-43.50
-40.35
-37.05
-33.60
-30.15
-26.70
-23.10
-19.50
-15.90
-12.15
-8.55
-5.25
-1.95
1.35
4.05
6.90
9.75
12.45
15.75
18.90
22.05
25.05
28.20
31.20
34.20
37.05
39.90
42.60
45.30
48.00
50.55
53.10
55.35
57.75
60.00
62.10
64.20
66.15
67.95
69.75
71.40
73.05
74.55
75.90
77.10
78.30
79.50
80.55
81.30
82.20
82.95
83.55
84.00
84.45
84.75
84.90
85.05
85.05
84.90
84.75
84.45
84.15
83.55
83.10
82.35
81.60
80.70
79.65
78.60
77.55
76.20
74.85
73.35
71.85
70.20
68.40
66.60
64.65
62.55
60.45
58.35
55.95
53.70
51.15
48.75
46.05
43.35
40.65
37.80
34.95
32.10
29.10
25.95
22.95
19.80
16.65
13.50
10.20
7.05
4.20
1.50
-1.35
-4.50
-7.80
-11.10
-14.70
-18.30
-21.90
-25.50
-28.95
-32.40
-35.70
-39.00
-42.15
-45.30
-48.30
-51.15
-54.00
-56.70
-59.25
-61.65
-64.05
-66.30
-68.40
-70.35
-72.30
-73.95
-75.60
-77.10
-78.45
-79.65
-80.70
-81.60
-82.50
-83.10
-83.70
-84.15
-84.45
-84.60
-84.75
-84.60
-84.45
-84.15
-83.70
-83.10
-82.35
-81.45
-80.55
-79.35
-78.15
-76.80
-75.30
-73.65
-72.00
-70.05
-68.10
-66.00
-63.75
-61.35
-58.95
-56.40
-53.70
-50.85
-47.85
-44.85
-41.85
-38.70
-35.40
-32.10
-28.65
-25.05
-21.60
-18.00
-14.40
-10.80
-7.05
-3.90
-0.60
2.55
5.40
8.10
10.95
14.10
17.25
20.25
23.40
26.40
29.40
32.40
35.25
38.10
40.95
43.65
46.20
48.75
51.30
53.70
55.95
58.20
60.30
62.40
64.35
66.30
68.10
69.75
71.40
72.90
74.25
75.60
76.80
77.85
78.90
79.80
80.70
81.45
82.05
82.50
82.95
83.25
83.55
83.70
83.70
83.70
83.55
83.25
82.95
82.50
81.90
81.30
80.55
79.65
78.75
77.70
76.50
75.30
73.95
72.45
70.95
69.30
67.65
65.85
63.90
61.95
59.85
57.60
55.35
53.10
50.70
48.15
45.60
42.90
40.20
37.50
34.65
31.80
28.80
25.80
22.80
19.65
16.65
13.50
10.20
7.05
4.35
1.65
-1.20
-4.35
-7.50
-10.80
-14.40
-18.00
-21.45
-25.05
-28.50
-31.80
-35.10
-38.40
-41.55
-44.55
-47.55
-50.40
-53.25
-55.80
-58.35
-60.90
-63.15
-65.40
-67.35
-69.30
-71.25
-72.90
-74.55
-75.90
-77.25
-78.45
-79.50
-80.40
-81.30
-81.90
-82.50
-82.95
-83.25
-83.40
-83.40
-83.25
-83.10
-82.80
-82.35
-81.75
-81.00
-80.10
-79.05
-78.00
-76.65
-75.30
-73.80
-72.15
-70.50
-68.55
-66.60
-64.50
-62.25
-59.85
-57.30
-54.75
-52.05
-49.35
-46.35
-43.35
-40.35
-37.05
-33.90
-30.60
-27.15
-23.70
-20.25
-16.65
-13.05
-9.45
-6.30
-3.15
0.15
2.85
5.55
8.25
10.95
14.10
17.25
20.25
23.40
26.40
29.25
32.25
35.10
37.80
40.50
43.20
45.90
48.30
50.85
53.10
55.35
57.60
59.70
61.80
63.75
65.55
67.35
69.00
70.50
72.00
73.35
74.70
75.90
76.95
77.85
78.75
79.65
80.25
80.85
81.45
81.75
82.05
82.35
82.50
82.50
82.35
82.20
81.90
81.45
81.00
80.40
79.80
78.90
78.15
77.10
76.05
74.85
73.65
72.30
70.80
69.30
67.65
65.85
64.05
62.10
60.15
58.05
55.80
53.55
51.30
48.90
46.35
43.80
41.10
38.40
35.70
32.85
30.00
27.00
24.00
21.00
18.00
14.85
11.70
8.70
6.00
3.30
0.45
-2.25
-5.40
-8.55
-11.70
-15.30
-18.75
-22.20
-25.65
-29.10
-32.40
-35.70
-38.85
-41.85
-44.85
-47.85
-50.55
-53.25
-55.95
-58.35
-60.75
-63.00
-65.10
-67.05
-69.00
-70.80
-72.45
-73.95
-75.30
-76.50
-77.70
-78.75
-79.65
-80.40
-81.00
-81.45
-81.75
-82.05
-82.20
-82.05
-82.05
-81.75
-81.30
-80.70
-80.10];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Look at your data

First of all you should carefully look on your input data if your algorithm does not work as expected. Maybe it does what it is designed for but this is not what you expect. Some of your maxima are not clean local maxima. You have samples with exactly equal function values. I have drawn your data and magnified the first maximum to demonstrate it:
[image: Magnified first maximum of function data]

There are four values at index 165 to 169 that have identical numerical values. Your algorithm can not recognize a maximum of this shape.

### Solutions

I have three suggestions for you.

#### Add precision to your data

Firstly: Look deeper in your data. They may have more precision if you take all significant digits. With a closer look your peaks might have real local maxima.

#### Don't re-invent the wheel

If you can solve it in matlab/octave you could just use an existing solution already able to deal with complicated situation as this:
    [J,K]=findpeaks(fun,'DoubleSided')

This will give the expected result:

```
J =

  -1.5603
   1.5499
  -1.5315
   1.5263
  -1.5080
   1.5027
  -1.4844
   1.4792
  -1.4608
   1.4556
  -1.4399
   1.4347

K =

    83
   165
   249
   332
   415
   499
   581
   664
   745
   827
   909
   991
```

#### Use an improved algorithm

If you need to implement this method yourself you have to adapt your criterion for peak finding. For example you could use two single sided criteria and mark raising and falling and flat areas:

```
 c(i)=1*(fun(i-1) < fun(i)) + -1*(fun(i+1) < fun(i))
```

This expression will produce in matlab/octave a 1 value for raising signal parts, 0 for flat parts and -1 for falling parts.

Now you can search this array for some conditions:
If you find a place without raise or fall after a raise and before falling signal you found a maximum. You also find a maximum if a fall follows a raise immediately.